# Remove section name from header only from pages where the section starts

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrartcl

I would like to remove the section name from my header only on pages where a section starts. Also I would like to keep using `scrlayer-scrpage` because it's already implemented in my code. Of course I am also open for simpler solutions.

Thanks for your help.
Cheers,
Benson

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[headsepline,automark, draft = false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead{\pagemark}

\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit={\linespread{1}\selectfont}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\blindtext[11]

\newpage

\section{Second Section}
\blindtext[11]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[headsepline,automark,draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit={\linespread{1}\selectfont}}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{First Section}
    \blindtext[11]
    
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Second Section}
    \blindtext[11]
    
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want the rule to appear in the `plain` header as well, add the option `plainheadsepline`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,automark,draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit={\linespread{1}\selectfont}}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\thispagestyle{plain}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{First Section}
    \blindtext[11]
    
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Second Section}
    \blindtext[11]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Almost. I also want to keep the horizontal line in the header on the page wehre the section starts. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Interesting style, but easily achievable: just add the option ``plainheadsepline`` to ``scrlayer-scrpage``.

Comment: Also, a sorta off-topic remark: I noticed you where using ``\rohead`` (=right odd head). It doesn't make a difference for your one-sided document, but you should use the counterpart to ``i(nner)head`` namely ``o(uter)head`` as I did in my answer. Apart from being consistent, this also ensures your header would work with the option ``twoside`` as well. In a two-sided scrartcl ``\headmark`` also alternates between the section and subsection title, so if you want to use the section title only, use ``\leftmark``.

Comment: Unfortunately ```plainheadsepline``` takes away the horizontal line in the header which I always want to keep. Is there a way to get the horizontal line back? In principle your solution does what I need.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. ``plainheadsepline`` does not take away any horizontal line, it only adds one on ``plain`` pages. So ``\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline,automark,draft=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}`` should do exactly what you describe as your goal. (see edit)

Comment: Seems like I did a mistake while pasting your code into my project. Everything works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can let others know that your issue has been solved by accepting answers. ;)